# Why does the typescript transpiler not hoist variables?

Tags: typescript, transpiler

I understand that ES6 and TypeScript both support block level scoping, but when targeting ES3 and ES5 the output should be function level scoping. I think there has to be a logic behind why TypeScript isn't hoisting variables.. and I'm not running into a problem, I'm more just curious why it doesn't hoist variables.

For example, given the following TypeScript:

```
function seed(length: number, multiplier: number): number[] {
  let result: number[] = [];

  for(let i: number = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let n: number = i * multiplier;

    result.push(n);
  }

  return result;
}
```

The transpiler outputs:

```
function seed(length, multiplier) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var n = i * multiplier;
    result.push(n);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The result I would have expected would be one with the variable declarations hoisted to the top of the function. Looking something like this:

```
function seed(length, multiplier) {
  var
    i, n,
    result = [];

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    n = i * multiplier;
    result.push(n);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the compiler doesn't output code based on a coding standard. It tries to be as close as possible to the original input.

Note that `var` variables are hoisted behind the scenes anyway ([var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)). There's not a need for the TypeScript compiler to change the input in this case and doing so would needlessly increase its complexity.

Answer (score 4):

> I think there has to be a logic behind why TypeScript isn't hoisting variables.. and I'm not running into a problem, I'm more just curious why it doesn't hoist variables.

Exactly that. Because it isn't a problem, why go though the effort of hoisting?

Also in case of `let` It would actually be wrong to hoist it the way you showed.

## Temporal Dead Zone

Firstly `let` variables cannot be used before declaration like `var` variables could be. With var you would get `undefined`. With `let` you would get a `ReferenceError` due to *temporal deadzone*. Fortunately TypeScript will give you a compile time error anyways so you don't run into that at runtime :

```
console.log(a); // Error: Block scoped variable used before declaration 
let a = 123;
```

## Block Scoping

`let` variables declared in a `for` *are only available* in the for loop. This is because they are *block scoped* and not *function scoped*. [More on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html)

Again TypeScript will give you a compile time error if you misuse `let` (instead of you running into it at runtime):

```
for(let i: number = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
}  
console.log(i); // Error: no variable i in scope
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But output for ES3/5 used let, not var. So it could move the declaration to the top. But not much point in doing that in auto-generated code that has already been checked for correctness.