# ES6 import and hoisting of variable declarations

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hoisting

I have a simple file.  It looks like the following:

```
# foo.js
import store from './store'
console.log(store)
```

It imports a variable `store` from store.js:

```
# store.js
const store = createStore( ... );    
export default store;
```

If I `import foo from './foo'` in file X, console.log prints out the value of store.  However, if I import from file Y, console.log prints out `undefined`

What is going on?  How do I ensure that store is properly initialized regardless of whether I import foo in file X or file Y?

Comment: If it matters, I'm using react-native, babel, and the Chrome interpreter.

Comment: Can you share some more code please? What does `tmp.js` look like?

Comment: sorry, that was meant to say foo.js.  Updated.

Comment: Umm, have you looked at the output js? There's no native implementation.

Comment: The output is correct if imported from file X, but it's undefined if imported from file Y.  Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Do you potentially have circular dependencies in your modules? If you're importing from somewhere that the thing you are importing depends on, it might not have been assigned yet.

Comment: That's a really good question.  I don't see any obvious circles, but there could be a more subtle one.  Are there good tools for detecting circular dependencies?  I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-require but it didn't seem to work on react native

Comment: @emmby there's no native implementation of es6 modules. Babel is transpiling them behind the scenes into es5. It might be worth looking at the code that is actually running.

Comment: Potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807664/cyclic-dependency-returns-empty-object-in-react-native

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the typescript transpiler not hoist variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192564/why-does-the-typescript-transpiler-not-hoist-variables)