# TypeScript Type Hoisting "chicken or egg" problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, module

Before someone marks this as a duplicate, I checked 2 other questions that didn't actually solve anything. They were only ideas for alternatives ways to do the exact problem, but didn't show a solution to my problem.

When making an array in TypeScript, I assigned the type `any[]` to it, since I haven't imported the type of the array yet. However, I have to pass this array to a `require` statement to make class methods work on this particular array.

If I make the array first, (using `any[]`) then I won't be able to type the array.

```
let blockchain: any[] = [];

// Pass array to import classes and functions
const {/* stuff to import */} = require("./otherfile.js")(blockchain);
type BlockType = InstanceType<typeof Block>;

// How do I set blockchain's type to BlockType[]?
```

However, if I import the classes first, I won't be able to pass the array to give the correct array to class methods

```
// Pass array to import classes and functions
const {/* stuff to import */} = require("./otherfile.js")(blockchain); // error
type BlockType = InstanceType<typeof Block>;

let blockchain: BlockType[] = [];
```

Importing the module twice, first with an empty array just to obtain the class, is not an option for me, since the original import's class methods will push data to the empty array and it'll be pointless.

EDIT: To be more specific about the module classes, this is what happens inside the other file.

```
function exp(blockchain: any[]): Object {
    class Block {
        // public x: number, etc...
        
        constructor(
            // stuff...
        }

        static generate(/* params */): Block {
            // do stuff, edit properties...

            let block = new Block(/* args */);
            blockchain.push(block); // Array that was passed to module
            return block;
        }
    }
    
    return {
        Block: Block
    }
}
```

Scotty Jamison's suggestion wouldn't work here because the Block class from import #1 wouldn't be the same as the one from import #2, and their methods would push to different arrays.

```
let {Block1} = require("./otherfile.js")([]);
let blockchain: Block1[] = [];
let {Block2} = require("./otherfile.js")(blockchain);

Block1.generate("yo");
Block2.generate("foobar");

console.log(blockchain.length); // 1
```

Comment: "I checked 2 other questions that didn't actually solve anything. They were only ideas for alternatives ways to do the exact problem, but didn't show a solution to my problem"  Links to these please?

Comment: Either not relevant or not applicable to this situation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159495/typescript-hoisting
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192564/why-does-the-typescript-transpiler-not-hoist-variables

Comment: A couple of options I can think of off of the top of my head. 1. do an "import type" first, then re-import the exact same module further down. 2. Extract the types into a separate module.

Comment: Scratch my second suggestion. You're dealing with classes, so there's no easy way to define their types in a separate module. The first option would probably work though.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to do something. I can't do that since it'll mess with methods, but I didn't really go into detail. I'm gonna edit the post to further explain why @ScottyJamison

NVM, your second comment loaded in